# Issues with XConnect certificate does not contain Private Key

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, xconnect

I have a Windows Server 2016, SIF and Sitecore Fundamentals installed where I am trying to provision a Sitecore 9 XP1

Here is the error I am seeing

```
CERT:\LocalMachine\My\210E7393A00B188EEB841E22CB09BA5660D6C3E9 does not contain Private Key
```

I generated self-signed certificates for XConnect and XConnect Collection using a Powershell command

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName xconnect.local -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName xconnectcollection.local -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Then I have exported the certificate as PFX

```
$sslPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\210E7393A00B188EEB841E22CB09BA5660D6C3E9  -FilePath C:\temp\xconnectlocal.pfx -Password $sslPassword
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert cert:\LocalMachine\My\0486F9D98837A08726A238E1431F010B5256E99A  -FilePath C:\temp\xconnectcollectionlocal.pfx -Password $sslPassword
```

And manually imported on Trusted Root Certification

On xconnect-xp1-collection.json, I have modified the SSLCert to match XConnectCollection Thumbprint

```
"SSLCert": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The certificate to use for HTTPS web bindings. Provide the name or the thumbprint. If not provided a certificate will be generated.",
            "DefaultValue": "0486F9D98837A08726A238E1431F010B5256E99A"
```

When prompted during the SIF process, XConnectCert I then add the Thumbprint from XConnect.local SSL

[image]

Finally, I receive the 210E7393A00B188EEB841E22CB09BA5660D6C3E9 does not contain Private Key error
[image]

I have seen other similar questions

1. [Sitecore 9 XP0 XConnect Cert Requirements](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/sitecore-9-xp0-xconnect-cert-requirements)
2. [Issue with Sitecore 9 certificate missing private key](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/issue-with-sitecore-9-certificate-missing-private-key)

However, none of these solved my issue.

Any ideas what might causing the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Differently from XP1, the XP0 topology has a JSON file specifically for create the certificate - **xconnect-createcert.json**

[image]

After creating the certificate using xconnect-createcert.json, I have tried provisioning the XConnect-Collection as I was doing and the error went away.

[image]

Now, I wonder what am I missing while generating my certificates manually... well at least it worked and **XP0 package has the xconnect-createcert.json** which solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Try altering the certificate creation step to explicitly allow export of the private key.

So instead of:

> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName xconnect.local -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

Try this:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DNSName xconnect.local -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Normally when importing a key into the cert store through the Certificate Management UI you need to explicitly check the "make private key exportable" box, so I assume the default policy is to disallow export of the private key.

Comment: I changed the method to create the certificate and still receiving the same error... Any other idea?

Comment: When I used that method in testing, I was able to validate that the private key was present. Perhaps the error is misleading? Try putting a copy in the Trusted Root Certificate Authority store as well to ensure the very presents as valid in the snap in.

Comment: *verify  (not very)

Comment: I have XConnect SSL in Trusted Root Certification, and the certificate says "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate". Now, I wonder if is there any sequence to install the XP1 and I am deploying it wrong.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps I haven't got any information to contribute there at the moment I'm afraid.  I would raise that as a new question.