# xConnect INVALID CERTIFICATE

Tags: xconnect

I installed Sitecore 9, but I'm facing an issue with xConnect
I tried to Open the web https://xp0.xconnect and I see an error

> HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden Your client certificate is either not
>   trusted or is invalid.
>
> Module       IIS Web Core Notification       BeginRequest Handler
>   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code    0x800b0109

I used the Chris Auer installation guide, which is excellent and it also generates the Certificate as well.

On the Server Certificates, I can see the generated Certificates. I also tried to generate and Self Signed Certificated and Change, but all my attempts failed
Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: this is the installation guide that i used : http://www.waitingimpatiently.com/install-sitecore-like-a-ci-nerd/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8770/issues-with-xconnect-certificate-does-not-contain-private-key/8772 which seems to have a similar issue description

Comment: Jose, this is likely a duplicate, but can you specify how you are attempting to open the address? Are you using a browser or connecting with an application using the correct client certificate?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I´m using Windows 10, I tried just open on my browser: h t t p : / / xp0.xconnect (it opens) but if i put h t t p s : / / xp0.xconnect/ it fails

Comment: When you are opening web page are you seeing any popup..  ? If yes, then it means your xconnect is installed correctly. When popup opens if you click on cancel I guess you will see time stamp on the page . Please check once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

Run this query in Powershell.

Comment: hey @deepak dosaya, you mind describing what this script does so OP knows if this could help fixing the issue

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me recently when I tried to install a new certificate and put it in the Trusted Root Certificate Authority. Turns out, this makes Windows unhappy, as this store is meant for self-signed certificates. (A full explanation is in this KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2801679/ssl-tls-communication-problems-after-you-install-kb-931125)

What deepak's Powershell script does is identify the non-self signed certificates in that store and move them to the Intermediate Certificate Authorities store. I'll repeat it here:

```
Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\root -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.Issuer -ne $_.Subject} | 
    Move-Item -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\CA
```

I didn't figure this out myself, I read a few blog posts and other stack exchange answers, but this is what got me past the problem today.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I ultimately had to remove all of the DO_NOT_TRUST keys I could find, reboot, then reinstall using SIF for the error message to disappear.