# Sitecore 901 installation issue - Could not find Cert: mysite.xconnect_client in Cert:\Localmachine\My

Tags: xconnect, installation, certificate

when I am trying to install **Sitecore 9.0 update 1** in **my local PC** with the script provided in the installation guide I am getting this error.

```
[-------------------------------------------------------------- SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions: FilePermissions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------]
WARNING: Could not find Cert: sc901.xconnect_client in Cert:\Localmachine\My
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Unable to parse [ResolveCertificatePath(variable('Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The
running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cert:\Localmachine\My is not a valid Certificate Path"
At D:\Sitecore\Install901\install901.ps1:90 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:01
Transcript stopped, output file is D:\Sitecore\Install901\xconnect-xp0.200513 (2).log
GetConfigFunctionResult : Unable to parse [ResolveCertificatePath(variable('Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))] - Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running
command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Cert:\Localmachine\My is not a valid Certificate Path"
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1:182 char:20
+ ...      return GetConfigFunctionResult -FunctionText $InputObject -Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,GetConfigFunctionResult
```

also referred below link but it didn't help
[Sitecore 9 - XP0 - xConnect Cert requirements?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/sitecore-9-xp0-xconnect-cert-requirements)

**Note**: i have other `sitecore versions (9.0 Update 2, 9.1 & 9.2)` already running in my local. [image]

Comment: Please see these answers:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/sitecore-9-xp0-xconnect-cert-requirements
Hope, they help.

Comment: @Bharath C N, Did the above link help?

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean, no i looked into it, they have asked to use the script as per installation guide which i am already doing.

Comment: @Bharath C N, sorry, that I was unclear. There is the second answer, with certificates: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8269/6970
And also you need to use the correct version of SIF, as SIF was updated (from 1.2 to 2.0) with Sitecore 9.1.
You can find the more detailed instruction here, for example: https://www.valtech.com/insights/sitecore-9.1-and-sitecore-9.0.x-in-the-same-machine/